# Suppose M is a positive real number.Show that there are finitely many rationals in any interval with denominator(in least terms)less than M?

Tags: real-analysis

We use the above result frequently in real analysis.It would be helpful for me if someone gave me a formal proof of the above result.Are there some other such important results similar to my question?

Comment: I don't think you really mean a *formal* proof (which would be huge and unreadable), but just a argument in English prose...

Comment: Can someone give me a diagram showing this thing?

Answer (score 2):

There are finitely many possible denominators that are less than $M$. For each of these there are only finitely many *numerators* that give a fraction within your interval (and not all of those will be in lowest terms, but that doesn't matter).

A finite sum of (finite) naturals is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Note that any interval must contain a finite number of integers. Similarly, it contains a finite number of multiples of $\frac{1}{2}$, and a finite number of multiples of $\frac{1}{3}$, etc. up to multiples of $\frac{1}{\lfloor M \rfloor}$. This describes all fractions with denominator less than $M$, and a finite sum of finite numbers is finite.

[image]

**Edit:** As requested, a way to visualise this: basically we're just looking at Ford circles on a given interval having a radius that is at least some positive constant. Since these circles are all pairwise non-intersecting, and they lie in a finite region of the plane, obviously you can only fit a finite number of them given an upper bound on the radius.

Comment: Can it be visualized?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar is this visualisation good enough?

Comment: Yes that is awesome.I had never thought of such a thing before.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a, b)$ be your interval. Then consider the interval $(M!a, M!b)$. If $\frac pq$ is a fraction in least terms with $q \leq M$, and $\frac pq \in (a, b)$ then $M! \frac pq$ is an integer and $M!\frac pq \in (M!a, M!b)$. Since there are only finitely many integers in an interval, and multiplying by $M!$ is injective, it follows that there are finitely many rationals in $(a, b)$ that can be written as a fraction with denominator $\leq M$.

Comment: I want a picture showing that.